# Display current date in XML element

Tags: xslt, format

I'm using an XSL to transform one XML into another. My problem is that in one element I have to display the current date with the format:YYYYMMDD.

I tried using a variable like these:

```
<xsl:variable name="dateNow" select="current-dateTime()"/>
<xsl:variable name="dateNow2" select="current-date()"/>
```

And then tried to format then, but no success.

```
<FRUEHESTER_LIEFERTERMIN><xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime($dateNow, '[Y0001][M01][D01]')"/></FRUEHESTER_LIEFERTERMIN>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What exactly is happening (what does "no success" mean).  What XSLT processor are you using?

Here is a minimal test case of what you are trying to do (input XML document doesn't matter)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
&lt;xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"  exclude-result-prefixes="xs fn"&gt;

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="dateNow" select="current-dateTime()"/>
    <xsl:variable name="dateNow2" select="current-date()"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <FL><xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime($dateNow, '[Y0001][M01][D01]')"/></FL>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and here is what it produces -- do you get the same if you try this test case?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FL>20120111</FL>
```

Comment: Hi Murray. I tried with your example but I got 2012111, I'm starting to think that this could be due to the program I use to test xsls that is Altova XMLSpy2006.
The process is developed in Sonic. I will test it running the process and let you know.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Gerado -- I tried it using ALTOVAXML2012 and Saxon 9 HE -- both produced the same correct result.  Take care

Comment: I tested in my Sonic process and works perfect! The XMLSpy was removing the 0 from dates, damn tool. Thanks again Murray.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show date in the following format Wed, 27-Oct

Use following code in XML

```
                 <TextClock
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:format12Hour="EE, dd-MMM"
                  android:textColor="@color/gray_100"
                  android:textSize="15sp"
                  android:layout_gravity="center"
                  android:padding="5dp"
                  android:textStyle="bold" />
```

If you want to show time like 09:08

Use the following code in XML

```
                  <TextClock
                    android:id="@+id/time"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:format12Hour="hh:mm"
                    android:textColor="@color/gray_100"
                    android:textSize="60sp" />
```

if you want to show time with AM and PM use following code in XML

```
                 <TextClock
                    android:id="@+id/time"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:format24Hour="HH:mm"
                    android:textColor="@color/gray_100"
                    android:textSize="60sp" />
```